Images Uploaded to Strapi Are Not Visible in Admin Panel or Frontend
Hello Stack Overflow Community,
I'm experiencing an issue with viewing images uploaded to Strapi. Despite being logged in as a super admin and having connected to PostgreSQL, I am unable to see the images that were uploaded by another user.
Details:

Strapi Version: [e.g., 4.x.x]

Frontend Framework: Next.js

Database: PostgreSQL

Strapi Admin Panel URL: http://localhost:1337/admin


Steps Taken:

Checked Media Library:

I navigated to the Media Library in the Strapi admin panel, but the images are not visible.


Verified User Permissions:

As a super admin, I should have full access. I checked the roles and permissions, and the super admin role has the correct permissions to view media files.


Inspected Database:

I confirmed that images are listed in the upload table in PostgreSQL, indicating they were uploaded successfully.


Checked File System:

The images are present in the /public/uploads directory on the server.


CORS Configuration:

I have set up CORS to allow requests from my frontend domain (http://localhost:3000).


Network Requests:

Using browser developer tools, I verified that requests for images are being made, but they return errors or fail.


Strapi Logs:

There are no apparent errors related to media handling in the Strapi server logs.
Problem:
Despite all checks, images uploaded to Strapi are not visible in the Media Library or on the frontend of my Next.js application.
Questions:

Why are the images not visible in the Strapi Media Library?

What additional steps can I take to troubleshoot this issue?

Could there be an issue with Strapi’s configuration or the way images are served?







Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
